# Set values of one column to match results outcome of another column

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

I'm looking to change this output below. Instead of it being -999.99. I want the result to show <3.
[image]

We're wanting the Column **Reported As** that shows **<3.0** to show on the Report and NOT **-999.99**.
[image]
This is the following script that I am working with:

```
USE [HarvestSQL]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spRp20DataListData]
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME,
    @location VARCHAR(255),
    @patients NTEXT
AS

        EXEC ('
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            vwReportPortalMajorTest 
        WHERE 
            (DrawDate >= ''3/1/2006 00:00:00'') AND 
            (DrawDate < ''5/7/2006 00:00:00'') AND 
            (DrawLocation = ''Ameri-Tech Kidney Center Arlington'')
        ')

    DECLARE @date1String VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @date2String VARCHAR(40)
    SET  @date1String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date1,109)
    SET  @date2String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date2,109)
    IF @location = 'Charleston Renal Care' 
    BEGIN
        SET @location = 'Liberty Dialysis Petersburg'
    END
        EXEC ('
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            vwRp20MajorTest 
        WHERE 
            (DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''') AND 
            (DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''') AND 
            (DrawLocation =  '''  + @location + ''')
        ')
```

Any suggestions will help me out.

Here is another Stored Procedure that may help give more details:

```
USE [ReportPortal]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER   PROC [dbo].[spRp20DataListData]
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME,
    @location VARCHAR(1000),
    @patients NTEXT,
    @dynamicSqlSelectClause NTEXT,
    @dynamicSqlGroupByClause NTEXT,
    @suppressEmptyRows VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @resultsToQuery INT = 0
AS
    DECLARE @date1String VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @date2String VARCHAR(40)
    
    set @date2 = DateAdd(day, 1, @date2)

    SET @date1String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date1,109)
    SET @date2String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date2,109)
print @location

-- print SUBSTRING(@location,0, 7) 
-- print SUBSTRING(@location,7, (len(@location)-6))


IF SUBSTRING(@location,0, 12)  = 'Locations: '
    BEGIN
    print 'Running for Multiple Locations'
    set @location = SUBSTRING(@location,12, (len(@location)-11))
    print '@location updated to'
    print @location
    IF @resultsToQuery = 0 --All results
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('
                SELECT 
                    ' + @dynamicSqlSelectClause +  --PatientName,DrawDate,MAX((CASE WHEN NAME=''Albumin'' THEN NumberResult ELSE 0 END)) AS AlbuminResult
                ', PatientKey FROM 
                    vwRp20CompletedTest 
                WHERE 
                    DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''' AND 
                    DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''' AND 
                    DrawAbbrev IN  (' + @location + ') AND
                    PatientKey IN ( ' + @patients + ') AND
                    ((NumberResult <> 0) OR (Name like ''%Hepatitis%'')) '
                +  'GROUP BY ' + @dynamicSqlGroupByClause + ', PatientKey'
                )
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('
                SELECT 
                    ' + @dynamicSqlSelectClause + --PatientName,DrawDate,MAX((CASE WHEN NAME=''Albumin'' THEN NumberResult ELSE 0 END)) AS AlbuminResult
                ', PatientKey FROM 
                    vwRp20MajorTest 
                WHERE 
                    DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''' AND 
                    DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''' AND 
                    DrawAbbrev IN  (' + @location + ') AND
                    PatientKey IN ( ' + @patients + ') AND
                    ((NumberResult <> 0) OR (Name like ''%Hepatitis%'')) '
                +  'GROUP BY ' + @dynamicSqlGroupByClause + ', PatientKey'                      
                )
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    print 'Running for Single Location'
    IF @resultsToQuery = 0 --All results
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('
                SELECT 
                    ' + @dynamicSqlSelectClause + --PatientName,DrawDate,MAX((CASE WHEN NAME=''Albumin'' THEN NumberResult ELSE 0 END)) AS AlbuminResult
                ', PatientKey FROM 
                    vwRp20CompletedTest 
                WHERE 
                    DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''' AND 
                    DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''' AND 
                    DrawLocation =  ''' + @location + ''' AND
                    PatientKey IN ( ' + @patients + ') ' --Ended statement here 07032019 added single quote here.
                --  AND    --removed all this because the number result is breaking many reports. 
                --  ((NumberResult > 2.9) 
                --  OR (Name like ''%Hepatitis%'')) '-- unsure if removing this Hepatitis will break reports.
                +  'GROUP BY ' + @dynamicSqlGroupByClause  + ', PatientKey'
                + ' ORDER BY ' +  @dynamicSqlGroupByClause 
                )
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('
                SELECT 
                    ' + @dynamicSqlSelectClause + --PatientName,DrawDate,MAX((CASE WHEN NAME=''Albumin'' THEN NumberResult ELSE 0 END)) AS AlbuminResult
                ' ,PatientKey FROM 
                    vwRp20MajorTest 
                WHERE 
                    DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''' AND 
                    DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''' AND 
                    DrawLocation =  ''' + @location + ''' AND
                    PatientKey IN ( ' + @patients + ') AND
                    ((NumberResult <> 0) OR (Name like ''%Hepatitis%'')) '
                +  'GROUP BY ' + @dynamicSqlGroupByClause + ', PatientKey'                      
                )
        END 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Would really need to see what's happening under the hood with the stored procedure. Otherwise, you would really need to modify your SELECT * statement to also include a CASE statement if "if this, then that".

Something like

```
USE [HarvestSQL]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spRp20DataListData]
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME,
    @location VARCHAR(255),
    @patients NTEXT
AS

        EXEC ('
        SELECT 
            t.*,
            CASE WHEN t.[Aluminum] < -999 THEN ''<3'' ELSE NULL END AS [Reported As]
        FROM 
            vwRp20MajorTest t
        WHERE 
            (t.DrawDate >= ''3/1/2006 00:00:00'') AND 
            (t.DrawDate < ''5/7/2006 00:00:00'') AND 
            (t.DrawLocation = ''Ameri-Tech Kidney Center Arlington'')
        ')

    DECLARE @date1String VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @date2String VARCHAR(40)
    SET  @date1String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date1,109)
    SET  @date2String = CONVERT(VARCHAR(40),@date2,109)
    IF @location = 'Charleston Renal Care' 
    BEGIN
        SET @location = 'Liberty Dialysis Petersburg'
    END
        EXEC ('
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            vwRp20MajorTest 
        WHERE 
            (DrawDate >= ''' + @date1String + ''') AND 
            (DrawDate < ''' + @date2String + ''') AND 
            (DrawLocation =  '''  + @location + ''')
        ')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: I added a second script to the question. 
This was under another folder/query (I hope I said that correctly). 

Hope this helps give more details.